# How to write a 2D vector into a binary file?

Tags: c++, vector, 2d

everyone!
I have a 2D vector filled with unsigned chars. Now I want to save its contents into a binary file:

```
std::vector<std::vector<unsigned char> > v2D(1920, std::vector<unsigned char>(1080));

// Populate the 2D vector here
.....

FILE* fpOut;

// Open for write
if ( (err  = fopen_s( &fpOut, "e:\\test.dat", "wb")) !=0 )
{   
   return;
}

// Write the composite file
size_t nCount = 1920 * 1080 * sizeof(unsigned char);
int nWritten = fwrite((char *)&v2D[0][0], sizeof(unsigned char), nCount, fpOut);

// Close file
fclose(fpOut);
```

But, when I read test.dat, fill in a new 2D vector, and compare its entries with old ones. I find that the written contents are not the same as the original. Why? What wrong with my write statement? Would you please tell me how to write a 2D vector into a binary file in a right way? Thank you very much!

```
    #define LON_DATA_ROWS 1920
    #define LON_DATA_COLS 1080

    std::vector<std::vector<float> > m_fLon2DArray(LON_DATA_ROWS, std::vector<float>(LON_DATA_COLS));

    std::ifstream InputFile;

    int nSizeOfLonData = TOTAL_LON_ELEMENTS * sizeof(float);

    std::vector<char> vLonDataBuffer(nSizeOfLonData);

    // Open the file
    InputFile.open(m_sNorminalLonLatFile.c_str(), ios::binary);

    // Unable to open file pszDataFile for reading
    if ( InputFile.fail() )
       return false;

    // Read longitude data buffer
    InputFile.read(&vLonDataBuffer[0], nSizeOfLonData);

    // Close the file object
    InputFile.close();

    // Populate the longitude 2D vector
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < LON_DATA_ROWS; i++) 
    {   
        memcpy(&m_fLon2DArray[i][0], &vLonDataBuffer[(i * LON_DATA_COLS) * sizeof(float)], LON_DATA_COLS * sizeof(float));
    }

    // Some operation put here

    // Write the results to a binary file
```

Comment: Long story short: That's not a 2D vector, that's a vector of vectors. :)

Comment: For best working with 2D arrays, you can roll up your own little class (wrapping a single vector and supporting access operations by x,y), should be less than 1 screen of code. Or if you like Boost you can use  boost::multi_array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is wrong. The data contained by `v2D` is NOT in contiguous memory. However, each element of `v2D` (which is a vector) is in contiguous memory. That is, the data contained by `v2D[i]` is in contiguous memory.

So you should do this:

```
int nWritten = 0;
for(size_t i = 0; i < v2D.size(); i++ )
{
   if ( v2D[i].size() > 0 )
     nWritten += fwrite(&v2D[i][0], sizeof(unsigned char), v2D[i].size(), fpOut);
}
```

Or you can use C++ IOStream as:

```
std::ofstream file("E:\\test.data", std::ofstream::binary);
for(size_t i = 0; i < v2D.size(); i++ )
{
    if ( v2D[i].size() > 0 )
    {
       const char* buffer = static_cast<const char*>(&v2D[i][0]);
       file.write(buffer, v2D[i].size());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! But the result was the same as mine.

Comment: @GoldenLee: Now, you need to tell us what is the file, and what do you expect?

Comment: Dear Nawaz: I possibly make a mistake when convert my 2D vector elements. In fact, All elements of my 2D vector are allocated in a continuous memory block. I just logically split a 1D vector to a 2D vector for access covenience. Thank you very much!

Comment: @GoldenLee: A vector allocates it's own memory. You're mistaken; a vector of vector is not guaranteed to have contiguous memory. Post more code, and other info.

Comment: Your explanation is right. Actually, The code snippet posted here is only for demo purpose. In my product program, my 2D vector keeps image data. I have a test by using both my method and yours. I got the same picture! They are all right! That's just a coincidence. I don't know why.

Comment: @GoldenLee: But your method is wrong. If you're getting correct (expected) output, you're just being lucky (or rather *unlucky*, as it hides the problem).

Answer (score 3):

A vector of vectors in memory do not look like this:

```
|---------|---------|---------|---------|...   (where "-" is one element)
     0         1         2         3
```

But rather like this:

```
|->0x48267a70|->0x894753b2|->0xb8cc92f0|->0x22d8cc71|...
```

(each vector has a pointer to its internal data which will be reallocated when the growth is over the amount of the already allocated memory).

What you did was you took the address of the internal buffer of the first vector and overindexed it after exhausting its elements. That is undefined behaviour and that's why you got memory junk in your file (but you had an equal chance of crashing the program).

You can write the stored vectors one by one to the file by iterating. In a more idiomatic C++ style:

```
std::ofstream outfile("e:\\test.dat", std::ios::binary | std::ios::out);
if (!outfile.is_open()) ... // handle error

for (std::vector<std::vector<unsigned char> >::iterator it = v2D.begin();
     it != v2D.end();
     ++it)
{
    outfile.write(&it->front(), it->size() * sizeof(unsigned char));
}
```

Or, in C++11 the above will look like this:

```
for (auto& it : v2D) 
{
    outfile.write(&it.front(), it.size() * sizeof(unsigned char)); 
}
```

In both cases, `ios_base::failure` exceptions should be handled.

Comment: When you use *range-based* `for` loop of C++11, the loop variable would be `std::vector<unsigned char>`, not iterator, which means, `it->front()` should actually be `it.front()` (and similarly `it.size()`).

Comment: Also, use reference to avoid copy : `for (auto & v : v2D) { outfile.write(&v.front(), v.size() * sizeof(unsigned char)); }`

Comment: @Tamás Szelei: Thank you very much. Both Mr./Ms. Nawaz and you are kindly suggest that I should use a outer loop to make sure that the 2D vector is written correctly to a file. I'll correct my misunderstanding to the storage (self-management) of vector and other STL containers. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There are two major ways of doing 2d matrix: 
by defining a n*m memory area or by having a list of n pointers to m vectors. you have a variation of the latter.

what you're doing is writing a list of vectors data to the file... Your data is **not contiguous**, so you're writing the "vector" class instance data to the file.

You can write each of the sub vectors one by one, or to use 1920 * 1080 single vector, and write to file it just as you did.