# How can one export a re-readable Neural Network object to a file in C++?

Tags: c++, file, vector

The Neural Network program I am creating has hit a small... snag. Between http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/49924/ and [How to write a 2D vector into a binary file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8193590/how-to-write-a-2d-vector-into-a-binary-file), I cannot identify an adequate means of printing this Network object to a file that can be read-back by the program for later use:

```
class Network {
    struct DNA {
        vector<int> size;
        // size[layer]
        vector<vector<double>> bias;
        // bias[layer][neuron]
        vector<vector<vector<double>>> weight;
        // weight[layer][neuron][input]
    };

    double fitness;
    DNA geno;
}
```

I would hardly call this a problem... if each sub-vector was the same size. To compound the problem, these files must be human-readable for analysis.

The most recently-attempted form is as follows:

```
    Layer0(2)
        Biases(2):0.2,-0.1
        Weights(2x2):0.1,0.2;-0.9,-0.22
    Layer1(3)
```

In parentheses are the sizes of the vectors required to read-in. The semicolon is meant to separate the weights associated with each neuron. I got lost when trying to devise a method of reading the weights.

```
    string tmp;

    // get weights.
    getline(netFile, tmp, '(');
    getline(netFile, tmp, 'x');
    weight.resize(atof(tmp.c_str()));

    for (int i = 0; i < weight.size() - 1; i++) {
        vector<double> tWeight;
        getline(netFile, tmp, ')');
        tWeight.resize(atof(tmp.c_str()));
        getline(netFile, tmp, ':');
        for (int j = 0; j < tWeight.size() - 1; j++) {
            getline(netFile, tmp, ',');

            // THIS IS WHERE I GOT LOST.
        }
    }
```

My plan was to get a 2-D vector to push_back upon the weight vector of "geno."

A little help would be appreciated. If there is a means of writing the entire object (or at least, the structure) in binary, and reading it in, I can easily manage with writing 2 files (the network, and the human-readable source).

Comment: When it comes to human-readable serialization formats, JSON is generally my default.  There are lots of good C++ JSON libraries out there; a quick google should find some.

Comment: "Human-reabale neural networks". Good luck with that. We have a big enough problem understanding their functioning given an actual input; the mere weights are all but meaningless. But you're overthinking the complexity here. Yous simple network is fully-connected. Hence, If layer X has N nodes (+1 bias), and layer X+1 has M nodes, then you have (N+1) * M weights between them. It follows that a good format saves the network _form_ first. This is also the most human-understandable part. Only then save all the weights.

Answer (score 0):

The following means appears to be the most efficient fit-for-purpose method that is human-readable and program-readable.

```
Network layers=3
Layer0 size=2
    Neuron0 weights=2
        bias=0.441833
        weight=-0.366638
        weight=-0.197266
    Neuron1 weights=2
        bias=-0.104614
        weight=-0.958435
        weight=0.515015
Layer1 size=3
    Neuron0 weights=2
        bias=0.669617
        weight=0.0291748
        weight=0.43103
    Neuron1 weights=2
        bias=0.476379
        weight=-0.204041
        weight=0.502686
    Neuron2 weights=2
        bias=0.761475
        weight=0.0259399
        weight=0.249878
Layer2 size=1
    Neuron0 weights=3
        bias=0.371033
        weight=0.390442
        weight=0.776672
        weight=0.935242
```

Printing of the vectors in this manner is trivial, and similar in structure to the method by which the network imports it. This is the resulting file-based constructor.

```
Network(ifstream& netFile) {
    fitness = NULL;
    string tmp;

    // read layerCount.
    getline(netFile, tmp, '=');
    getline(netFile, tmp);
    geno.size.resize((int)atof(tmp.c_str()));

    geno.bias.resize(geno.size.size());
    geno.weight.resize(geno.size.size());

    // for all layers.
    for (int layer = 0; layer < geno.size.size(); layer++) {
        // read size.
        getline(netFile, tmp, '=');
        getline(netFile, tmp);
        geno.size[layer] = (int)atof(tmp.c_str());

        geno.bias[layer].resize(geno.size[layer]);
        geno.weight[layer].resize(geno.size[layer]);

        // for all neurons.
        for (int neuron = 0; neuron < geno.size[layer]; neuron++) {
            // read weightCount.
            getline(netFile, tmp, '=');
            getline(netFile, tmp);
            geno.weight[layer][neuron].resize(((int)atof(tmp.c_str())));

            // read bias.
            getline(netFile, tmp, '=');
            getline(netFile, tmp);
            geno.bias[layer][neuron] = atof(tmp.c_str());

            // for all weights
            for (int input = 0; input < geno.weight[layer][neuron].size(); input++) {
                // read weight.
                getline(netFile, tmp, '=');
                getline(netFile, tmp);
                geno.weight[layer][neuron][input] = atof(tmp.c_str());
            }   
        }
    }
}
```